# Efficient way for rest calls inside same container

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey-2.0

I am looking for away to make “internal” rest calls from a service entry point into rest services that are declared in the same war file.

Currently, I am using http connection to localhost. However, I believe dispatching the request directly (with requestDispatcher ?) will be more efficient - no need for connection, no need for extra execution threads, no need to send data via tcp socket, etc.

When I need the “internal” call, I do not know what is the actual object that will represent the payload, or the class/method that will process the request. All I have is the url, and a json string for the payload. I expect the response to be a json string.

Is there a standard method that will work for all rest container (e.g. using the servlet api) or using specific functions of Jersey/spring ?

Comment: If it is within the same war, why not directly calling the method to avoid objects serialization/deserialization?

Comment: In my API, The user is allowed to post use a schedule call. E.g., there is a service like “POST deffered/rest-call”, which will execute the rest-call at a later time. Any url/payload can be passed.

Comment: Don’t know the details of your app. If that controller delegates to service to do the actual scheduling, you can call that service directly. If no avail, you can try with Spring’s `RestTemplate` or Jersey to call that api `@localhost`.